# Why double import of NPM package in Typescript (Firebase Functions)

Tags: typescript, firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore

In [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) I came across this:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import 'firebase-functions';
admin.initializeApp();
```

Why the second import of `firebase-functions` ?

And where it should be, inside each modules or just main index.ts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the source code https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/master/src/index.ts firstly they are exporting objects so `import * as` is importing objects. And `import 'firebase-functions';` is calling if statement in 56 line

Comment: Good catch. One thing I don't get it, it was by chance I saw this, I didn't use it before and didn't have any negative effects.